# Using fixed type constraints inside an interface in Java?

Tags: java, generics, constraints

```
interface I1 { ... }
interface I2 { ... }
interface I3 { ... }
interface I4 { ... }

interface MyFactory {
  Object<? extends I1 & I2 & I3> createI1I2I3(); // doesn't work
  Object<? extends I2 & I3 & I4> createI2I3I4(); // doesn't work
}
```

Is there a trick to do it? I was thinking about things like

```
interface I1I2I3 extends I1, I2, I3 { ... }
```

But `I1I2I3` != `<? extends I1 & I2 & I3>`. There's a reason I just can't use this approach - `I1`, `I2` and `I3` are foreign code.

**Update**

For those who curious why might someone need such a weird thing:

```
interface Clickable {}
interface Moveable {}
interface ThatHasText {}

interface Factory {
  Object<? extends Clickable> createButton(); // just a button with no text on it
  Object<? extends Clickable & ThatHasText> createButtonWithText();
  Object<? extends Moveable & ThatHasText> createAnnoyingBanner();
}
```

Comment: I got to learn the use-case for such a construct ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` doesn't accept type parameter You can use the following construct instead:

```
interface I1 {  }
interface I2 {  }
interface I3 {  }
interface I4 {  }

interface MyFactory {
    public <T extends I1 & I2 & I3> T createI1I2I3(); 
    public <T extends I2 & I3 & I4> T createI2I3I4(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your return type should be parameterized, so you can do

```
interface MyFactory {

   <T extends I1 & I2 & I3> T createI1I2I3();

}
```